# count equivalence classes of the equivalence relation

Tags: combinatorics, equivalence-relations

Let $\simeq$ be an equivalence relation in the set of $n\times n$ matrices, with $0$ and $1$ coefficients, defined by $A \simeq B$ if and only if $A$ and $B$ has the same number of $1$s.

Determine how many different equivalence classes exist.

Is there a formula to count the number of matrices?

Comment: Is the number of different equivalence classes nxn?

Comment: The number of ones can be any integer from $0$ to $n^2$ (inclusive), so the total number of equivalence classes is $n^2+1$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:*

- There are $2^{n^2}$ possible $0$-$1$ matrices.
- There are $\binom{n^2}{k}$ $0$-$1$ matrices with exactly $k$ ones.